# use rtabmap/grid_map for move_base

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, roomba, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can not get move_base to work with the rtabmap grid_map.
I used this link to try and get some direction http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/StereoOutdoorNavigation and changed the openni_points to my laserscan but whenever i send a command the robot will just start to rotate (recovery behaviour?) in place.
I am using an roomba 780 as vehicle with an Kinect mounted on top of it for navigation and 3D mapping.
Even when using the Pointcloud2 variable it will instantly go into recovery mode.d

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249015/use-rtabmap/grid_map-for-move_base/) by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2016-11-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest to read the navigation stack tutorial for more ducumentation on move_base's parameters used: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup

`openni_points` is a `PointCloud2` `data_type`, if you want to use a laser scan, it should be `LaserScan` `data_type`. See tutorial above.

Your setup is also similar to Turtlebot, you may look at this tutorial as well: http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/MappingAndNavigationOnTurtlebot

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on 2016-12-13**:
Hi matlabbe when using the second link i keep getting problems, my move_base_node won't react to goals anymore also my local costmap still shows an empty map for some reason

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-12-13**:
The local costmap is independent of rtabmap, there should be an error with parameters namespace. What are your launch files and move_base yaml files?